# Cant find Second Highest Element in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am newbie in java so please kindly bear me and help me out in this small issue.

I want to calculate the second largest element in the following snippet.
How can i do this? Thanks in Advance.

```
public class Marathan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {``
    String[] names = { "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil",
        "Matt", "Alex", "Emma", "John", "James", "Jane", "Emily",
        "Daniel", "Neda", "Aaron", "Kate" };
    int[] times = { 341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412,
        393, 299, 343, 317, 265 };

    for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {

        System.out.println(names[i] + "..." + times[i]);

    }

     double max=times[0];
double mix=times[0];
     for(int x=0;x<times.length;x++){     
        if (times[x] > max) {
            max = times[x];

        }
        if(times[x]<mix){
            mix=times[x];

        }


    }
        System.out.println("The Fastest Runner is  " + max);
        System.out.println("The Slowest Raccer is "+mix);


}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int max1,max2;
if(times[0]>times[1])
{
    max1=times[0];
    max2=times[1];
}
else
{
    max1=times[1];
    max2=times[0];
}
for(int i=2;i<times.length;i++)
    if(times[x]>max1)
    {
        max2=max1;
        max1=times[x];
    }
    else if(times[x]>max2)
        max2=times[x];
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Marathan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String[] names = {"Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil",
        "Matt", "Alex", "Emma", "John", "James", "Jane", "Emily",
        "Daniel", "Neda", "Aaron", "Kate"};
    int[] times = {341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412,
        393, 299, 343, 317, 265};

    for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {

        System.out.println(names[i] + "..." + times[i]);

    }

    double max = times[0];
    double mix = times[0];
    for (int x = 0; x < times.length; x++) {
        if (times[x] > max) {
            max = times[x];

        }
        if (times[x] < mix) {
            mix = times[x];

        }

    }
    System.out.println("The Fastest Runner is  " + max);
    System.out.println("The Slowest Raccer is " + mix);

    // If there are at least 2 values in times
    int i1 = 0; // index of the largest
    int i2 = 1; // index of the 2nd largest 
    if (times[i1] < times[i2]) {// then swap
        int x = i1;
        i1 = i2;
        i2 = x;
    }
    for(int i = 2; i < times.length; ++i) {
        if (times[i] > times[i1]) {
            i2 = i1;
            i1 = i;
        } else if (times[i] > times[i2]) {
            i2 = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The first is " + names[i1] + " with a time of " + times[i1]);
    System.out.println("The second is " + names[i2] + " with a time of " + times[i2]);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your code looks neatly with proper indentations. I also do not guess what role **double mix** plays in the code. Now to the problem, try this:

```
double max = times[0];
double secondHighest = times[0];
     for(int x=0;x<times.length;x++){     
        if (times[x] > max) {
            max = times[x];
            secondHighest = highest;

        }
        else if ((times[x]>secondHighest) && (times[x] != max))
        {
            secondHighest = times[x];
        }
```

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely try this too! :)